# Delete Calculated field in Azure SSAS-Tabular modal

Tags: azure, modal-dialog, analysis, ssas-tabular, bim

I am using Azure Tabular Analytics. I have the *.bim file where I added few calculations. Over the period, I kept creating new calculation fields but did not removed the old ones that are not in use. Now that I need to cleanup my project, how do I know which calculated field is not referenced anywhere by another calculated field? I don't want to accidently remove the fields in use. I was expecting something like rt. click on the field and see the option to get referenced fields but can't find anything. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out: https://docs.tabulareditor.com/te2/Best-Practice-Analyzer.html#finding-unused-objects

Comment: Thanks for the response. Looks like this 2.x version is unable to run this script. 3.x is paid version so haven't tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative way to find all references. Rt.click the *.bim file and select View Code. The loaded page will show the json code of your Bim file. Search for the calculated reference field name. If it's occurrence is only for once, it is not used anywhere else and is safe to delete from View Designer.